# Responsive image-duo

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'll try to make my question as clear as possible.

I have the goal to do a mobile interface in hmtl and js, with Mapping button, I have a background with a Cellphone in it at the center, and the image of the Interface to put in the phone. What I need is for it to be responsive and to make the interface stay in the cellphone of the background which is responsive too.

If someone could help me to make match these two responsive image it would be great.

```css
#container {
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-image: url("http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/POIcall/Background.jpg");
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 1080px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  padding-left: 38.7%;
  padding-right: 38.7%;
  padding-top: 9%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
#Interface {
  width: 22.2%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
#appel {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 6;
  margin-left: -80px;
  margin-top: -35px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#fondtel {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 4;
  margin-left: -90.5px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#video {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 4;
  margin-left: -91px;
  margin-top: -193.5px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#message {
  width: 22.2%;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
}
#Background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div style='background: transparent url("http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/POIcall/Background.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0% 0% / 100% auto; width: 100%; height: 1080px; margin: 0px auto; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 9% 38.7% 10%; position: relative;'
id="container">
  <MAP NAME="menu">

    <AREA id="Bouton1" SHAPE="rect" COORDS="29,216,63,239" HREF="#">
    <AREA id="Bouton2" SHAPE="rect" COORDS="67,216,128,239" HREF="#">
    <AREA SHAPE="rect" COORDS="29,216,148,177" HREF="">
    <AREA SHAPE="rect" COORDS="29,216,148,177" HREF="">
    <AREA SHAPE="rect" COORDS="29,216,148,177" HREF="">
    <AREA SHAPE="rect" COORDS="29,216,148,177" HREF="">
    <AREA SHAPE="rect" COORDS="29,216,148,177" HREF="">
    <AREA SHAPE="rect" COORDS="29,216,148,177" HREF="">
    <AREA SHAPE="rect" COORDS="29,216,148,177" HREF="">
  </MAP>

  <video id="video" webkit-playsinline="" preload="auto" src="untitled_files/cyclamed.mp4" style="position:absolute; width:181px;height:191px;"></video>
  <img src="untitled_files/fondtel.jpg" id="fondtel" style="position:absolute;">
  <img onclick="playAndHideOverlay(this)" style="position:absolute;" id="appel" src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/POIcall/appel.jpg">
  <img src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/POIcall/Interface.jpg" id="Interface" usemap="#menu" style="" border="0">
  <img src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/POIcall/spam.jpg" id="message" style="margin: 0px;">
  <img src="" id="Background">

</div>
```

Comment: Can you share a JSFiddle of the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the image tag with id **Background**, and added it to **#container** as background image.

```css
#container {
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: transparent;
background-image: url("http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/POIcall/Background.jpg");
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position: 0 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
box-sizing: border-box;
height: 100vh;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 0;
max-height: 1080px;
max-width: 2000px;
padding-bottom: 10%;
padding-left: 38.7%;
padding-right: 38.7%;
padding-top: 9%;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}
#Interface
{
 width:22.2%;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:2;
}
#appel
{

top:50%;
left:50%;
z-index:6;
margin-left:-80px;
margin-top:-35px;
visibility:hidden;
}
#fondtel

{
top:50%;
left:50%;
z-index:4;
margin-left:-90.5px;
margin-top:-50px;
visibility:hidden;
}
#video
{
top:50%;
left:50%;
z-index:4;
margin-left:-91px;
margin-top:-193.5px;
visibility:hidden;
}
#message
{
visibility:hidden;
z-index:3;
}

#Background
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
max-width:100%;
z-index:1;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div style='' id="container">
  <video id="video" webkit-playsinline="" preload="auto" src="untitled_files/cyclamed.mp4" style="position:absolute; width:181px;height:191px;"></video>
  <img src="untitled_files/fondtel.jpg" id="fondtel" style="position:absolute;">
  <img onclick="playAndHideOverlay(this)" style="position:absolute;" id="appel" src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/POIcall/appel.jpg">
<img src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/POIcall/640x960.jpg" id="Interface" usemap="#menu" style="" border="0">
  <img src="http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/POIcall/spam.jpg" id="message" style="margin: 0px;">
  <img src="" id="Background">
  
</div>
```

Comment: I have several question :    1) is that normal ? in fullscreen mode i have that : (the bot of the image is cut , and the interface move from the phone)         2) There's a way to stop the display of the background with this method ? because i need to remove it when the page is too small thanks

Comment: You can increase the height of the **#container**, I have updated the code. On smaller screens, you can run this command to remove image`$('#container').css('backgroundImage','');`, and to add it back just give the url again, `$('#container').css('backgroundImage','url("http://slpubmedias.tf1.fr/test_nocache/test_jf/POIcall/Background.jpg")');`

Comment: i have updated mine and set height of the container to 1080 but it's still cut at the bottom , maybe cause of the padding ?

Comment: You always want the image to take up 100%of the screen, or keep it centred if the screen size is exceeding let's say 1500px?

Comment: Btw if i may ask you one question more , if i'd like to add an image more , as a message on the screen how could i do to make it responsive and fixed to the interface ? thanks a lot

Comment: Please update the CSS for **#container** from the answer. Just copy the style given for **#Interface** for the other image also, and just position it using top,bottom,left or right property.

Comment: Glad it solved your problem, if you still face any problem in this you can post it here in the comment section.

Comment: Sahil may i disturb you a bit ? may you open an hangout discussion with me please to not flood this topic ? add : Galietti.jeanfrancois@gmail.com Thanks , I'm actually meeting the same problem again ,  i'm not able to set the image in the phone at the good place , if you could explain me the method , thx a lot (code updated) as you can see the image is a bit too hight , and when i try to correct it with margin or top:% , it do not work , may you explain me a solution ? thanks

Comment: Sure @Jeff, I have sent you an invite

Answer (score 1):

You can add `class="img-responsive"` in img tag

```
<img src="640x960.jpg" id="Interface" class="img-responsive" BORDER="0" USEMAP="#menu" style="position:absolute;">
<img src="Background.jpg" id="Background" >
```

Comment: to do what about this class ?